# Can I use Code Igniter with Concrete5?

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks, content-management-system, concrete5

I am building a site that will (obvisouly) have a front end public portion that I want to drive with Concrete5, but then it will also have a members section that I would like to build with Code Igniter.

Does anyone have any idea how I could do that?

I guess I could just throw the Code Igniter code into a sub directory, but would I run into any issues with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i can't see why not.

As you suggested a separate folder on the site would be one solution.
(you might have to tweak the .htaccess file (if you are using one) to ignore the other cms/framework

Another solution would be to have separate subdomains,
eg example.com and members.example.com

Comment: The sub-domain approach would probably be bullet proof.

Answer (score 1):

The answer, since the OP hasn't posted it, is to change the .htaccess rule:

```
RewriteBase /
```

to:

```
RewriteBase /foo/
```

where `foo` is your subdirectory that the index.php and CI reside.  This .htaccess should also be in the same folder as the CI index.php.  Works like a charm.  Also don't forget to add the subdirectory to the base_url config setting.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a sub directory for Code Igniter.  I had to change the .htaccess file and Mod_Rewrite rules for apache in order for the Code Igniter "pretty" URLs to work correctly.

I will post the code later if I remember.